# While publing app on playstore got : Please upgrade to Billing Library version 3 or newer to publish this app

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

While publing app on playstore got : Error We've detected this app uses an unsupported version of Play billing. Please upgrade to Billing Library version 3 or newer to publish this app.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you have a question? The errors seem quite clear as to what is required(upgrading the dependencies used by your app).

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got solution , I just updated all deprecated libraries.

I was using Flutter 1.22.4, I migrated my project to Flutter 2.5.3 (Latest one as of nov-2021) everything solved.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, here is some workaround worked for me.
In your `android>app>build.gradle` add following line in dependencies.

`implementation ('com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0'){ force = true }`